# Bit manipulation with or mask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, mips, bitmask

Suppose I have a variable inst which holds an encoded MIPS instruction. I want to set the rt field to 0 without changing the other fields. The rt field is a 5-bit field indexed from 16-20. I first tried:

```
inst = inst & ~(1 << 16);
```

which sets the rt field to 0. Then I want to put the value of a new variable new_reg into the rt field. I tried:

```
inst = inst | (new_reg << 16);
```

Could anyone confirm whether these two lines of code are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your first bitmask.  The command (1 << 16) only masks the first bit, where you want to mask all of the bits from 16-20.  Try:

```
inst = inst & ~(0x3f << 16)
```

Then:

```
inst = inst | (new_reg << 16);
```